# How to record video in iOS which will be played in android

Tags: android, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, video-recording, avassetexportsession

I need to record video in iOS and want to play that video on android. I am using following code to record video in iOS via UIImagePickerController. The recorded video is played in iOS successfully but not in android. I am recording video in .mp4 format

```
imagePicker            = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate   = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage]
    self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 12
    self.imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeIFrame960x540
    self.imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = .Off
    self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Video
```

Comment: What video player are you using on the Android device?

Comment: Default Android player.

Comment: Have you tried a different video player such as [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) or [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en)?